# Reducing the amount of negations in (binary) rule induction mining

Tags: classification, cart, association-rules

I have been using rule induction mining (e.g., using C4.5) to extract rules out of healthcare and text data sets (binary features and outcome) but I always end up with rules containing way more negative terms (absence of drugs or words) than positive (presence of drugs or words).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to reduce the amount of negative terms? I could not find any example of methods that deal with this problem.